# my C# app save nothing to sqlite database

Tags: c#, sqlite

i have problem with sqlite !
in my c# app i using a little  database based on sqlite, i can select and see database data but the problem is that and when i try to insert a record into the table i see it in the program and it's worked well but and added to my DB but when i close the program and open the DB nothing saved :( and when i'm using my app this seems it's added to database but in realtime i'm using firefox addons to see database or when close and open app nothing saved.

```
SQLiteConnection ObjConnection = new SQLiteConnection("Data Source=Data/data.db3;");

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{        
    SQLiteCommand ObjCommand = new SQLiteCommand("SELECT * FROM PERSON", ObjConnection);
    ObjCommand.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
    SQLiteDataAdapter ObjDataAdapter = new SQLiteDataAdapter(ObjCommand);
    DataSet dataSet = new DataSet();
    ObjDataAdapter.Fill(dataSet, "Person");
    dataGridView1.DataSource = dataSet.Tables["Person"];
}

private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string name = textBox1.Text;
    string last = textBox2.Text;
    string q1 = "INSERT INTO Person(Firstname,Lastname) VALUES(?,?)";
    SQLiteCommand cmd1 = new SQLiteCommand(q1, ObjConnection);
    cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SongName",name);
    cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ArtistName",last);
    ObjConnection.Open();
    cmd1.ExecuteNonQuery();
    ObjConnection.Close();

    SQLiteCommand ObjCommand = new SQLiteCommand("SELECT * FROM PERSON", ObjConnection);
    ObjCommand.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
    SQLiteDataAdapter ObjDataAdapter = new SQLiteDataAdapter(ObjCommand);
    DataSet dataSet = new DataSet();
    ObjDataAdapter.Fill(dataSet, "Person");
    dataGridView1.DataSource = dataSet.Tables["Person"];
}

private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ObjConnection.Open(); 
    ObjConnection.ChangePassword("123"); 
    ObjConnection.Close();
}
```

Comment: It would really help readability if you'd write one statement per line...

Comment: try to open and commit a transaction

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems a problem with the connection String, SQLite would be using in your case a temporary database. [Temporary Databases](http://www.sqlite.org/inmemorydb.html) are automatically deleted when the connection that created them closes.

```
Data Source=Data/data.db3;
```

Just to discard my solution, could you try with an exiting absolute path (c:\Data):

```
Data Source=c:\\Data\\data.db3;
```